# Felicity judgement for English sentence

Tags: english, semantics

I wanted to ask English speakers what they think of the following sentence.

1. John left three years before Bill arrived. In fact Bill never arrived.

Is this an acceptable sentence? If not, could you identify what you don't like about it?

Comment: Well, _before_ presupposes Bill's arrival, but the next sentence denies it. It's not really a matter of felicity; it's more inconsistency.

Comment: It's acceptable English, though the speaker changed his mind in the middle.  What is conveyed is unacceptable, but the English is fine.